# Overwrite CSS with without deleting it

Tags: child-theme, css

I have some css in the theme that I am using, I want to keep the stock style.css  without deleting any of it. I want to use my child-theme style.css to remove or hide some values of a class. I would like to do this so I do not have to update my css with each new theme update.

This is what is in the stock theme

```
.et_pt_portfolio_entry {
border: 1px solid #dadada;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
background: #fff; 
padding: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

This is what I want to use in its place

```
    .et_pt_portfolio_entry {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    }
```

Normally I use display:none but I want to keep that class displaying, I just want to remove the other values without deleting the stock file.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your child theme set up correctly, placing the following CSS in it which simply resets some of the preset values should get you all the way there.

```
.et_pt_portfolio_entry {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: transparent; 
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you!